# Using the update method to control sprite animations in Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I friends, I will be very gratefull for any answer, a thanks in advance, this is my problem:

In pyglet this is the basic code to update a sprite in the screen:

```
sprite.x=50
pixels=10
def update(dt):
    if move_right == True:
        sprite.x += pixels * dt
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60.0)
```

This results in the sprite moving from point x to the right at 10 pixels speeed per second if the Right key was pressed.

But lets assume I need to move exactly from point X1 to point X2 at a variable and **STOP** exactly at point X2, how I would do that?

Imagine this:
**x_start=20**
**x_finish=40**
I want to move from x=20 to x=40, and **stop** at x=40. Pixels per second can be any value, lets assume 10 pixels in this example.

If I use the usual code I could do:

```
sprite.x=20  
pixels=10  
def update(dt):  
    if sprite.x != 40:  
        if move_right == True:  
            sprite.x += pixels * dt  
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60.0)
```

This would not work, because **pixels*dt** is not equal to **10**, **dt** is irregular and a float (1/60=0.01, 0.01*10=**0.1**, and dt is irregular too, so sometimes is 0.01, others is 0.019, others 0.021...etc), so each time the update executes the sprite.x evolution is something like this --> 10, 10,1, 10,24, 10,38, 10.51...etc

So, the **if sprite.x != 40:** would never work (because sprite.x will allways be a **float** and hardly will be 40) and my player will never stop.

I know that this problem my have a very easy solution but I have no clue and I am in despair. I am beggining my journey in pyglet so I am very ignorant at this stage, and need help to find a solution, I cant find a way out.

Is there other techniques to update a sprite every frame without using **sprite.x += pixels*dt**? Are there other solutions?

Very very gratefull,
Best regards from Portugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
sprite.x=20  
pixels=10  
def update(dt):
    if sprite.x != 40:  
        if move_right == True:  
            sprite.x = min(sprite.x + pixels * dt, 40)
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60.0)
```

Comment: It worked very well! I was surprised for the simplicity of the answer, I tried a lot of complicated functions and with such a clean code you resolved my problem. I am beginning in the ways of python, so I lack a lot of knowledge, I did not know the min() function, I am studying it now. I need to study a lot more. Thanks a lot friend, very gratefull! :-)